# C# Task.Run slowing my wpf program

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, performance

Short story:
I am designing software to validate some things in a CAD application. When I try parallelism it gets very slow in WPF only.

Long story:
I have my software that asks questions of my library (.dll) that I also made and that library communicates with my CAD software(E3.series from Zuken).

My software was originally made in WinForms and everything was good but the interface I thought would really benefit from WPF because of the binding. So I went and translated that, but found it's way slower. So I did 2 mini projects to find where it was getting a lot slower. Here are the results and I can't find why:

This code is just as fast as Winforms (3.5 sec) :

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    List<Wire> wires = e3.Project.Wires;
    timer.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show("WPF " + wires.Count + " in " + timer.Elapsed);
}
```

But when I do this it's (12 sec) :

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();
            List<Wire> wires = e3.Project.Wires;
            timer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("WPF " + wires.Count + " in " + timer.Elapsed);
        });
}
```

It's exactly the same with a `BackgroundWorker`.

I need to use `Task.Run` and `Parallel.ForEach` because I have a lot of long tasks to parallelize. My WinForms application got 5-6 times faster when I changed to `Parallel.ForEach` so I don't want to lose that gain for switching to WPF.

I see my CPU is running higher with the empty WPF window so it might be that there isn't enough CPU for my CAD application to work and answer my dll?

What I think I discovered with CPU usage analyser in VS2015 is that it's really the COM call from my library to my CAD software that are a lot slower because of my app.

Comment: _would really benefit from WPF because of the binding_ - `Winforms` support binding as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both a WinForm and WPF application UI runs in a Static Thread Apartment(STA) model.  You mention that using either Task.Run or Background worker degrades performance.  Since both of these create Multi-Threaded Apartment (MTA) threads, the issue may be due marshaling if the COM component is created in a STA.  See the "Mixed Model Development" section of [Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms809971.aspx) for more information.

You could try creating a STA thread and run your code on that.

```
Thread t = new Thread(ThreadWorkMethod);
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

Comment: didn't manage to do what you said because I didn't knew how to wait for this thread to be finished but at the end creating my E3 object within my new thread did it for me instead of creating before and using it in my new thread.

Comment: @user3704628, typically you don't wait for a thread to finish, but rather provide a mechanism such as raising an event to signal its completion.  Another option is to pass a delegate to invoke on the UI thread that points to a method to execute; this is really a more direct method as opposed to an event which is nothing but a candy coated way to invoke a delegate.  Any way, I'm glad for the feed back that it solved your issue as I knew about the possibility of this, but never experienced it.  It would also help others, if you could mention the name of your CAD software in you original post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not be called MessageBox.Show inside the thread pool because they are not setup as user interface threads.

Second, make sure the e3.Project.Wires property does not perform any user interface actions either.

Third, try using the following method to queue work for the thread pool...

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadProc, e3);
```

...implementing the method like this...

```
static void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo) 
{
    ??? e3 = (???)stateInfo;
    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    List<Wire> wires = e3.Project.Wires;
    timer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("WPF " + wires.Count + " in " + timer.Elapsed);
}
```

Obviously you would need to cast the incoming parameter to the correct type.

Comment: with this code I managed to get my WinForms as slow as my WPF Window(11 sec)  and I also saw that e3.Project.Wires calls a ton of time the cad software and this is normal but 1 call takes 25 ms instead of 4 ms when I use this technique so the problem is really a side effect that makes the CAD software 6 time slower to answer.

Comment: `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` is same as `Task.Run` without benefits of `async-await`